# Localstack [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

I know there are a litany of other SO questions on this topic but I have tried all of the suggestions to no avail.

Environment I am running this on is Windows 10 Professional.

#### setup.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Creating SQS queue"
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue
```

#### Localstack.Dockerfile

```
FROM localstack/localstack:3.2

COPY --chown=localstack localstack-scripts/setup.sh /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh

RUN chmod u+x /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  document-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: document-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mysql"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "document-db"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  localstack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /localstack-scripts/LocalStack.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
    container_name: localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
localstack   | 2024-03-20T14:51:09.634 ERROR --- [  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR): [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh'
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

I have ensured that all the line endings on the `setup.sh` files are LF and I have even used https://app.execeratics.com/LFandCRLFonline/?l=en to convert the file, but to no avail.

At this point I am so close, but so far.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're building your own Dockerfile with the setup file included? You can also just mount the setup.sh file into the container by adding to `volumes`: `- localstack-scripts/setup.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh`.

Comment: @thrau - I am doing that because I am running on a Windows machine and there is no way to `chmod` a file on Windows. So if I use a volume mount it will not work as the `setup.sh` will not be executable.

Comment: OK that's good to know! Frankly we haven't really tested this particular feature well with Windows. (I'm the author), or in the scenario that you're using it. Can you go full `+x` or `777` and see what happens? Maybe it's related to the user owner. Normally when files are mounted they belong to the default user.

Comment: @thrau - thanks for your response. I have tried both:

`RUN chmod 777 /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh` and `RUN chmod +x /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/setup.sh` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by creating my `setup.sh` from the WSL2 command line in the end.

```bash
echo '#!/bin/bash' > localstack-scripts/setup.sh
echo '' >> localstack-scripts/setup.sh
echo 'echo "Creating SQS queue"' >> localstack-scripts/setup.sh
echo 'awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue' >> localstack-scripts/setup.sh
```

It appears that https://app.execeratics.com/LFandCRLFonline/?l=en wasn't doing what I hoped it would do.

Comment: Wow great catch! Glad you got it working